# App icon missing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

My App icon is missing with this Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The resources are in the correct place and I don't do nothing strange with the manifest. I think that is a problem with the deploy to the device with Android Studio, because when I use an old Manifest obtained from the VCS, the problem continue.

The original Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

For the deploying, I use the default run configuration of Android Studio or an Android Application.

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED**:
The problem is in this line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

If I put in this place the following line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

The icon is back.

Comment: press Ctrl on @mipmap/ic_launcher to check if ic_launcher exist or not

Comment: Yes, exist. The problem must be other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

If I put in this place the following line:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

The icon is back.